# Storing output of multiple unix command to a file and mail it

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to store the output of the following commands to a file. Every time I'm executing this it is getting stuck.

```
 cat >/u01/app/orcpprod/hccdba/bkpchklog.log <<EOL
echo " "
date;
echo "====================="
echo "DATABASE BACKUP CHECK"
echo "====================="

#RMAN Backup in Progress
echo "RMAN Process Info"
ps -ef|grep rman


#Error in alert log
echo "Check the error count "
tail -30 /var/opt/oracle/backups/CPPROD/BACKUP_CPPROD.log


#Displays the errors if they are present
echo "Errors if any"
egrep "RMAN-|ORA-|Error|ERROR|^cp|^gzip|^tar" /var/opt/oracle/backups/CPPROD/BACKUP_CPPROD.log


#Backup Start Time
echo "Backup Start Time"
head -1 /var/opt/oracle/backups/CPPROD/BACKUP_CPPROD.log

#Backup End Time
echo "Backup End Time"
tail -n 19 /var/opt/oracle/backups/CPPROD/BACKUP_CPPROD.log| grep -i Finished

#Size of the backup
echo "Backup Size"
cd /u02/backup/rman_bkp_wkly/CPPROD/day1
du -sk rman_data* | awk '{ sum += $1} END {print sum/1024 "M"}'

EOL

#Mail info
mail -s /u01/app/orcpprod/hccdba/bkpchklog.log "$ORACLE_SID :: Backup Check Info" deepak.goel@hitachiconsulting.com
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable.

Comment: Which command is getting stuck?  The creation of the script or the `mail` part?  What ends up in `/u01/app/orcpprod/hccdba/bkpchklog.log` in case you interrupt the hung process?

Comment: This is not your main problem, but if you don't quote `EOL` as in `'EOL'`, the `$1` in the awk command is expanded, most likely to the empty string, in your output file.

Comment: Wait, do you want the *output* of these commands? You're storing the commands themselves. You should use `{ commands; } > output.log` instead of your here-doc.